How to test x86 app with DotnetBenchmark and x64 sdk
I have an x86 netcore3.1 application that tests perfectly with dotnetbenchmark if I specify the path to the x86 sdk in Job. But the x64 sdk also allows you to build x86 applications, so I would like to use it
but I did not get a "BadImageFormatException". Is it possible?
